# Nesting multiple 'for' loops

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am using Django 1.8.3 and Python 3.4.3

My application is starting to get large and I have several 'for' loops to access several objects within the same model.  Although I am new to Python, I am guessing there is a more streamline way of preparing my code.  Please see a small snippet below.  The model is 'day_of_week' yet I have a 'for' loop for several objects.  I also placed a snippet of the template code for a complete picture.  Thank you for your help.

views.py

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EmailListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
        months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October',
                  'November', 'December']
        subject_type = ['Offer', 'Sell', 'Fear', 'Learn']
        content_type = ['Offer', 'Sell', 'Fear', 'Learn']
        email_list = ['FMGB', 'FMGR', 'AE', 'IBA']

        total_campaigns = {}
        total_campaigns_month = {}
        total_recipients = {}
        total_unsubscribes = {}
        total_bounces = {}
        total_open = {}
        total_clicks = {}

        for day in days:
            total_campaigns[day] = Email.objects.filter(day_of_week=day).count()
        for recipients in days:
            total_recipients[recipients] = Email.objects.filter(day_of_week=recipients).aggregate(
                Sum('recipients')).get('recipients__sum', 0.00)
        for unsubscribes in days:
            total_unsubscribes[unsubscribes] = Email.objects.filter(day_of_week=unsubscribes).aggregate(
                Sum('unsubscribes')).get('unsubscribes__sum', 0.00)
        for bounces in days:
            total_bounces[bounces] = Email.objects.filter(day_of_week=bounces).aggregate(Sum('bounces')).get(
                'bounces__sum', 0.00)
        for open in days:
            total_open[open] = Email.objects.filter(day_of_week=open).aggregate(
                Sum('open')).get('open__sum', 0.00)
        for clicks in days:
            total_clicks[clicks] = Email.objects.filter(day_of_week=clicks).aggregate(
                Sum('clicks')).get('clicks__sum', 0.00)
```

Template Snippet... (email.html)

```
{% if email_list %}
    <tr>
       <td>Monday</td>
       <td>{{ total_campaigns.Monday }}</td>
       <td>{{ total_recipients.Monday }}</td>
       <td>{{ total_unsubscribes.Monday  }}</td>
       <td>{{ total_bounces.Monday  }}</td>
       <td>{{ total_open.Monday  }}</td>
       <td>{{ total_clicks.Monday  }}</td>
       <td>{% average total_open.Monday total_recipients.Monday %}</td>
       <td>{% average total_clicks.Monday total_open.Monday %}</td>
    </tr>
    ...
```

Comment: Could you create a function called "initialize" (or something like that) that takes in what you are trying to iterate over as well as any additional variables in order to slim down duplicate code to a single for loop? Does that make sense?

Edit: The first answer below looks good to me. My suggestion would require making a much of calls to the same method with just different parameters.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Before I start implementing the solution, would it be too much to ask if you could provide this noob an example of your suggestion using different parameters?  Thank you.

Comment: Sure I will attempt a sample briefly, but I warn you that I am also a noob :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should do the very same:

```
for day in days:
    total_campaigns[day] = Email.objects.filter(day_of_week=day).count()
    # recipients
    total_recipients[day] = Email.objects.filter(day_of_week=day).aggregate(
        Sum('recipients')).get('recipients__sum', 0.00)
    # unsubscribes
    total_unsubscribes[day] = Email.objects.filter(day_of_week=day).aggregate(
        Sum('unsubscribes')).get('unsubscribes__sum', 0.00)
    # bounces
    total_bounces[day] = Email.objects.filter(day_of_week=day).aggregate(
        Sum('bounces')).get('bounces__sum', 0.00)
    # open
    total_open[day] = Email.objects.filter(day_of_week=day).aggregate(
        Sum('open')).get('open__sum', 0.00)
    # clicks
    total_clicks[day] = Email.objects.filter(day_of_week=day).aggregate(
        Sum('clicks')).get('clicks__sum', 0.00)
```

and i'm not overly familiar with the django ORM, but you probably can reduce the number of database queries with

```
for day in days:
    day_objects = Email.objects.filter(day_of_week=day)
    total_campaigns[day] = day_objects.count()
    # recipients
    ...
```

...etc (and replace all `Email.objects.filter(day_of_week=day)` with the newly defined `day_objects`)

Comment: This worked great - getting rid of all the extra 'for' statements is very nice! - thank you!!  Have a great weekend.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not totally sure if this is all correct syntax, but perhaps you might try this approach?

```
def initialize_dict(dict, days, dict_name):
    for day in days:
        if dict_name='':
            dict[day] = Email.objects.filter(day_of_week=day).count()
        else:
            dict[day] = Email.objects.filter(day_of_week=day)
                       .aggregate(Sum(dict_name))
                       .get(dict_name + '__sum', 0.00)
```

I'm not sure whether this is a better solution, but it is an alternative. You could decide to make the days a global variable instead of having to pass it into the function. A couple of sample calls would be:

```
initialize_dict(total_campaigns, days, '')
initialize_dict(total_recipients, days, 'recipients')
```

and so on... I hope this helps. Please feel free to critique this solution on why it is either a good or bad approach! I am still learning and improving myself :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to try and help with this. I went with the solution from 'hiro protagonist' because it seemed easier for me to understand, especially while I'm still sorting this all out :)  Thank you again, Have a great weekend.

Comment: No problem! Enjoy your weekend as well.